# Manually add link to HTMLAnchorElement

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  const element: HTMLDivElement = this.myElement.nativeElement;    
  const myLink: HTMLAnchorElement | null = element.querySelector('a');
```

since I'm getting myLink always as null, my question is:
how can I manually insert link address so I can properly debug and test myLink variable behavior.

I tried with

```
element.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');
```

but still myLink is set to null.

Comment: That's not Javascript. Please add the correct tags - and only those.

Comment: I'm using js code to manipulate dom elements

Comment: Maybe you meant to `HTMLAnchorElement || null` (`or`)?

Comment: @connexo Typescript, I'd think (most all JS operations are still valid)

Comment: set where? in typescript? It changes the link on a page -> https://jsfiddle.net/qs2k0ht5/2/

Comment: You don't have an anchor element in the first place. `element` is a div, which does not have an `href` attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to add an `href` link at all. Your selector isn't looking for `href`, it's looking for any anchor tag.

Comment: @melpomene ok, how can I insert anchor tag instead?

Comment: `element.appendChild(document.createElement('a'))`, at least in JS. No idea about TypeScript.